# Babel doesn't wrap results in verbatim

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Here's an example:

```
   #+NAME: sys5
   #+HEADER: :exports both
   #+BEGIN_SRC maxima :results raw
     programmode: false;
     solution: triangularize(coefmatrix(
     [ -3*x - 11*y + 7*z = 0,
        2*x +  6*y - 2*z = 0,
          x +  2*y +   z = 0],
          [x, y, z]));
     print(solution);
   #+END_SRC

   # (1)
   #+RESULTS: sys5
   : [ - 3  - 11   7  ]
   : [                ]
   : [  0    4    - 8 ] 
   : [                ]
   : [  0    0     0  ]
   # (2)
   #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
     [ - 3  - 11   7  ]
     [                ]
     [  0    4    - 8 ] 
     [                ]
     [  0    0     0  ]
   #+END_EXAMPLE

   Triangulated matrix of the above solution doesn't have pivot in the third
   column, thus it doesn't have a unique solution.
```

(1) is printed like so: `[-3 -11 7] [] [0 4 -8] [] [0 0 0]`, but (2) prints properly, i.e. every line on the separate line. Interestingly, if there's some text after the `#+RESULTS:`, then export doesn't add `=` around the result, otherwise, it does.

Is there anything special about `[]` in results?

Answer (score 1):

You clearly did not [consult the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/results.html#results) before posting this.  Upon reading the manual, you will not only know that you could have gotten what you desired result by using the header `#+BEGIN_SRC maxima :results value verbatim` or `#+BEGIN_SRC maxima :results value code` you will also know that `raw` means raw Org code.

Comment: No need to use such bold statements. The options above were copied from Maxima manual. Knowing that implementing these options is a responsibility of the programmer who writes the `ox-<exporter>.el` you wouldn't be so confident about what you say. Besides, the version of the manual you linked to is relatively new. Some of those options didn't exist few years ago.